# How to change nnoremap for different file types?

Tags: vim, vi

When I hit `<leader>r` inside a PHP file, I want to do:

```
 nnoremap <leader>r ifile_put_contents(ini_get('error_log'), '');<cr>error_log(print_r(, true));<esc>
```

But when I do the `<leader>r` inside a JS file, I want to do:

```
 nnoremap <leader>r iconsole.log();<esc>
```

How could I do this?

I also want to position the cursor inside the `console.log/print_r`. Any idea how to do that as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use autocomand and map to the buffer only. Here's an example:

```
augroup quick_debug
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType php nnoremap <buffer> <leader>r ifile_put_contents(ini_get('error_log'), '');<cr>error_log(print_r(, true));<esc>
  autocmd FileType javascript nnoremap <buffer> <leader>r iconsole.log();<esc>

augroup END
```

To move cursor around you can use `<left>` and `<right>` before `<esc>`. Like this: `nnoremap <buffer> <leader>r iconsole.log();<left><left><esc>`.

If you don't mind using plugins you could take a look at the UltiSnips and use snippets instead of mappings.

Comment: You can also add mappings to after-directory ftplugin files. e.g. `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim`. See `:h after-directory` and `:h ftplugin`.

Comment: May also consider creating a custom [surrounding](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround). Use an autocmd or ftplugin to set a buffer local variable. e.g. `autocmd FileType php let b:surround_{char2nr('r')} = "file_put_contents(ini_get('error_log'), ''); error_log(print_r(\r, true));"`. See `:h surround-customizing` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can define that for certain filetypes by prepending `:autocmd Filetype {filetype} ...`, and put that into your `~/.vimrc`. But that gets unwieldy as you add mappings and other settings for various filetypes. Better put the commands into `~/.vim/ftplugin/{filetype}_mappings.vim`. (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`.)